# How to read and process stdout values in ant - exec?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, ant

To validate a file with an executable.
I have ant script target as:

```
<target name="xtest" depends="xyz" description="Additional check">
    <exec executable="${xtest.exe}" failonerror="true" resultproperty="retVal">
        <arg value="${inputfile.dat}" />
    </exec>
    <echo>Returned: ${retVal}</echo>
</target>
```

Output on console:

```
xtest:
     [exec] Errors:          3
     [exec] Warnings:        1
     [exec] Infos:           0
     [exec] Total:           4
     [echo] Returned: 0
```

The exit code (`${retVal}`) of executable is `0` even if it detects error. 
I want to terminate the process if Errors are more than `0`.

How can I read first output line (`[exec] Errors:          3`) and parse the value which is `3` in above example and terminate the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked exactly with code below. Thanks!

```
<target name="xtest" depends="xyz" description="Additional check">
    <exec executable="${xtest.exe}" failonerror="true" resultproperty="retVal" output="output.txt">
        <arg value="${inputfile.dat}" />
    </exec>
    <echo>Returned: ${retVal}</echo>
    <property file="output.txt" prefix="xtestoutput"/>
    <fail>
        <condition>
          <not>
            <equals arg1="${xtestoutput.Errors}" arg2="0" />
          </not>
        </condition>
    </fail>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `resultproperty` you can redirect output of your executable to a file.
Then, since the output matches property file format you can read that output file and use the properties in it like:

```
<target name="xtest" depends="xyz" description="Additional check">
    <exec executable="${xtest.exe}" failonerror="true" resultproperty="retVal" output="output.txt">
        <arg value="${inputfile.dat}" />
    </exec>
    <echo>Returned: ${retVal}</echo>
    <property file="output.txt" prefix="xtestoutput"/>
    <fail>
        <condition>
            <not>
                <equals arg1="${xtestoutput.Errors}" arg2="0" />
            </not>
        </condition>
    </fail>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks @guleryuz.
worked after couple of changes.
1. changed `outputproperty` to `output`
2. 
` <condition>
            <equals arg1="${xtestoutput.Errors}" arg2="0" />
        </condition>` 
to
`<condition>
    <not>
     <equals arg1="${xtestoutput.Errors}" arg2="0" />
    </not>
   </condition>`